# Which scheme would be the best one for client users relation in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, schema

I'm very new with mongodb was reading some examples about relations but still can get into it, maybe because I was stack with sql for too long. So I have a table Clients, and table Users I've red that in MongoDB I can do embed something like this

```
db.clients.findOne()
{
  id  : '1',
  name: 'Client',
  users : [
     { name: 'User 1', id: '1' },
     { name: 'User 2', id: '2' }
  ]
}
```

or 
two separated tables

```
  clients : [
     { name: 'User 1', id: '1'}
  ]

And

  users : [
     { name: 'User 1', id: '1', clientId:'1'  },
     { name: 'User 2', id: '2', clientId:'1'  }
  ]
```

Assuming that clients & users would be a lot as entries which way is better? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I think found a something for guys who have the same dilema they can try this one http://openmymind.net/Multiple-Collections-Versus-Embedded-Documents/#11

if someone want's to explain more in deep or point another resoure can feel free to do it.